# Azure Function - Get Environment Variable Returns Null

Tags: azure, azure-functions, environment-variables

I'm trying to test an Azure Function locally but all of my environment variables are returning null. At some point I did delete and add back the local.settings.json file which I believe is the cause of the problem. I have set the "Copy to Output Directory" property on the local.settings.json file to "Copy if newer" but I am still facing this issue. Below is an example of the code that I am running that is returning null. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

```
string myURI = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myURI", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Comment: build action none and copy if newer should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code and settings, it worked successfully. As Thomas Suggested, keep the `Build action` to `none` and `Copy to output directory` to `Copy if newer` for the `local.settings.json` file.

But these options are set by default, I didn't keep explicitly. So, check the same settings available for your `local.settings.json`.

**Code**:
**Function1.cs**:

```
string myIDE = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IDE", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
string myURI = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myURI", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

log.LogInformation("Environment Variables are " + myURI + "and" + myIDE );
string responseMessage = "Hello Krishna, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. " + "The Environment Variables are" + myURI+ "and" + myIDE;
```

**local.settings.json**:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "IDE": "VS 2022 Community",
    "myURI": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/"
  }
}
```

[image: localsettingsjsonproperties]

**Output**:

[image: resultoflogging]